# Creating a view above an object

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to create a scene in Swift in which an object (object is a button) is clicked and it creates a pop-up window above the clicked building. I thought i had it down until it gave me an error saying, unexpected nil value when unwrapping an optional or something nasty like that. Here's the code. Thanks for any fixes you may have.

```
import UIKit

class BuildingUI {

//props
enum buildingTypes {
    case residential
    case commercial
}

var xValue : CGFloat = 0
var width : CGFloat = 0

//methods
func createBuildingView(xValue : CGFloat, width : CGFloat, buildingType : buildingTypes) {
    self.xValue = (xValue+(width/2))
    playScreenIns.BuildingView1.frame = CGRect(x: self.xValue, y: playScreenIns.PlayView.frame.height/10, width: (playScreenIns.PlayView.frame.width/5)*3, height: playScreenIns.PlayView.frame.height/4)
    playScreenIns.BuildingView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    playScreenIns.BuildingView1.layer.borderWidth = 2
    playScreenIns.BuildingView1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
    playScreenIns.BuildingView1.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    playScreenIns.scroller.addSubview(playScreenIns.BuildingView1)
}

}

var BuildingUIIns = BuildingUI()




import UIKit

class PlayScreen : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var PlayView: UIView!
var BuildingView1 : UIView!

@IBAction func CityHallPress(sender: UIButton!) {

        BuildingUIIns.createBuildingView(sender.frame.origin.x, width: sender.frame.width, buildingType: .residential)


}



}

var playScreenIns = PlayScreen()
```

Comment: there error it gives is on the line playScreenIns.BuildingView1.frame =

Comment: what class is "`createBuildingView`" in?  I don't see it, and I also don't see where you initialize (or set up) the "`PlayView`" property

Comment: so your BuildingUIIns you have a property `playScreenIns` what is `playScreenIns` ? I just noticed you instantiate playScreenIns. Your BuildingUI has no idea what playScreenIns is.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, and commenting. I believe what you want is

`BuildingUI` should inherit `UIView`

```
class BuildingUI: UIView {}
```

then in your `PlayScreen` the `BuildingView1` should be of type `BuildingUI`.

But, I am not so sure on what you're trying to do...are you doing this as experimental test in playground?

On a side note, you should name your your classes with a postfix to what kind of class your inheriting from for example

`BuildingUI` should be `BuildingView` and `PlayScreen` should be `PlayScreenViewController`

you should start your class properties with a lower case `BuildingView1` to `buildinvView1` like you do in `BuildingUI`. But its matter of taste I guess!